# Warning: openlog() has been disabled for security reasons in syslog_watchdog()

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, drupal-7

I have moved Drupal site to a new server. After that I have

> Warning: openlog() has been disabled for security reasons in
>   syslog_watchdog() (line 102 of
>   /home/fissionsof/domains/fissionsoft.co.th/public_html/modules/syslog/syslog.module).

How can solove this warning

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent most warnings from being shown by prefixing function call with "@" char [see docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) (i.e. `@foo()` instead of just `foo()`. So basically you need to edit mentioned file and add "@" to the line it lists). Or you can try to "quiet" PHP error reporting by doing `error_reporting(0);` as very first thing in the code or set it in your php.ini or via .htaccess. Or, enable `openlog()` if you can control your server configuration at that level.